# Display Contacts in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

when i have to open this page i want to display all contacts in  phone with out click on any button.
    Here myFunction() displays all contacts.

```
    I have to call `myFunction()`, in this code. I dont know where to call this function. Help me

            var ar1 = new Array;
            var ar2 = new Array;
            var name, number;
            var counter = 1;

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            function onDeviceReady() {
                var options = new ContactFindOptions();
                options.filter = "";
                options.multiple = true;
                filter = [ "displayName", "phoneNumbers" ];
                navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);               
            }

            function onSuccess(contacts) {
                 for ( var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                    for ( var j = 0; j < contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
                        name = contacts[i].displayName;
                        number = contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value;
                        ar1.push(name);
                        ar2.push(number);  

// here i called myFunction(), but it's displaying one contact in multiple times                    
                         }
                    // here i called myFunction(), but it's displaying one contact in multiple times 
                    }
// Here i called myFunction(), the function is not calling
            }

            function onError(contactError) {
                alert('onError!');
            }

    //  where to call this function 
            function myFunction() {

                 $("#checkall").click(function() {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $(":checkbox").attr("checked", true);
                    } else {

                        $(":checkbox").attr("checked", false);
                    }
                }); 

                 for ( var i = 0; i < ar2.length; i++) {

                    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id",
                            'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
                    newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
                            '<input type="checkbox" value="'
                                    + ar1[i] + '"/>'
                                    + ar1[i] + "   " + "   " + ar2[i] + '</br>');
                    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

                } 
            }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>

            </br>

        <div id="TextBoxesGroup">
                <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" value="check" />selectAll</br> <br />
                    <br /> <br />
                </div>
            </div>

            </body>

        </html>
```

Comment: your question not stating what exactly u wanna to do.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot catch what you want exactly.

if you want to generating phonenumber checkbox list when your app starts,
just call myFunction() in end of onSuccess() callback.

if you want another time, you should define a event handler that you want like below.

```
$("#PhonenumberListButton" ).click( function() { myFunction(); } );
```

and your code can occur index exception during loop.

Let's think about below.

1. each contact has 1 name but has 1 or more phone numbers
2. your code pushes each name into ar1 and also pushes each phone numbers of contact into ar2
3. so ar2.length can be greater than ar1.length
4. your generating display code use ar2.length for loop. it should make exception if any contact has 2 or more phonenumbers.
   This's a reason of stop your loop in onSuccess().

**Fixed Code**

```
        function onSuccess(contacts) {
             for ( var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                name = contacts[i].displayName;
                ar1.push(name);

                ar2[i] = []; // array for multiple phone#.
                for ( var j = 0; j < contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
                    number = contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value;
                    ar2[i].push(number);
                }
             }

             myFunction(); // display phone numbers
        }

        function myFunction() {

             $("#checkall").click(function() {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(":checkbox").attr("checked", true);
                } else {

                    $(":checkbox").attr("checked", false);
                }
            }); 

             for ( var i = 0; i < ar2.length; i++) {
                if ( ar2[i].length ) {  // avoid none phone# exception
                    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id",
                            'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
                    newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
                            '<input type="checkbox" value="'
                                    + ar1[i] + '"/>'
                                    + ar1[i] + "   " + "   " + ar2[i][0] + '</br>');
                    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
                }
            } 
        }
```

Comment: i called myFunction(), end of onSuccess(), it's not working.  i have to display all contacts with out clicking any button

Comment: i updated answer about your code. plz let me know about your result :)

Comment: i tried with this code, myfunction() is not called from onSuccess()